# Solving a system of ODE's exact

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have

$$ \begin{bmatrix} y_1' \\ y_2' \\ y_3' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & - \alpha  & 0  \\ 0 & \alpha & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

with initial conditions $y_i(0)=1$ for $i=1,2,3$

We find the eigenvalues of jacobian mtrix to be $-1, -\alpha, 0$ so as long as $\alpha \geq 0 $, our solutions will be stable.

Once I find eigenctors, for the $0$ eigenvalue, the associated eigenvector is $(0,0,1)^T$ and for the $-1$ matrix the associated eigenvector is $(1, \frac{1}{\alpha-1}, \frac{\alpha}{1 - \alpha} )^T$ so the exact solution is

$$ y(t) = C_1 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + C_2 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{1}{\alpha-1} \\ \frac{\alpha}{1 -\alpha} \end{bmatrix} e^{-t} $$

but when using the inital condition, we obtain

$$ C_2 = 1 \; \; \text{and} \; \; \frac{C_2}{\alpha-1} = 1 $$

which suggests something may been wrong in my solution. Is my approach incorrect?

Comment: I haven't fully checked your calculations, but assuming it's correct, why does your solution $y(t)$ not contain a $e^{-\alpha t}$ term?

Comment: becasue the eigenvector assocaited with that eigenvalue is zero vector

Comment: I don't agree, consider $(0,1,-1)^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the eigenvalue $-\alpha$ has eigenvector $(0,-1,1)^T$, so the general solution is given by 
$$y(t)=c_1\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} + c_2\begin{pmatrix} \alpha -1\\ 1 \\ -\alpha \end{pmatrix} e^{-t} +c_3\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}e^{-\alpha t}$$
Edit. As another user mentioned, the solution breaks down whenever $\alpha=1$. In this we have two distinct eigenvalues; $0$ and $1$. But $1$ has only one corresponding eigenvector $(0,1,-1)^T$. The solution is now given by 
$$y(t) = c_1\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} + (c_2+c_3t)\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} e^{-t}$$

Comment: What if $\alpha = 1$? Wouldn't you need a generalized eigenvector in that case?

Comment: We'd need a $te^{-t}$ term.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but wouldn't it be important to state that point?

Comment: I agree with @Moo. It's important to state the special case in your answer

Comment: You're right, I added it to my comment.

Comment: I think you need there to be a generalized eigenvector  and I found that is $v_3 = (-1,1,0)$.